# Not getting 'Done' button in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a cordova app. In the app I open third party links using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.URLLink').click(function(){

var res=window.open(url,'_blank','location=yes');
});


});
```

This opens the link properly in Android App and displays 'close(x)' button.

Also in iOS if the URL is not having any URI appended to it opens the URL and shows 'Done' button.

But in one case it is opening the URL but not showing the 'Done' button. The URL has URI appended. Will that matter.

Comment: what do you mean by "has URI appended"? can you post an example?

Comment: url is like https://abc.efg.com?uid=a&res=b&qwe=c

Comment: It's showing done button to me. Can you make sure the url you load is correctly built?

Comment: I just replaced the URL and put google.com.. same thing..

Comment: which cordova ios version are you using? which inAppBrowser plugin version?

Comment: Cordova version 4.2.0.. how do I check plugin version?

Comment: using "cordova plugin list" command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89564/discussion-between-programmer-and-jcesarmobile).

Comment: Issue was because cordova.js path mentioned was wrong. It is resolved now. Thanks.